# How to add an object to an array on the first click and update one of its values with every click made afterwards

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am working on a React shopping cart and I am trying to accomplish the following based on an array that I will present after I explain my issues:

1) I am trying to check if the size that the client is requesting is available.

2) If it is not available I want to run a function that will:

2A) Add the chosen object to the array.

2B) On each subsequent click I want to update the stock to make sure that it alerts the client that the item is not in stock any more and I want to increase a new element that I want to call "quantity" by one.

3) This is my current array of sizes:

```
[ 0: size: 3 stock: 140
_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5566"

1: size: 3.5 stock: 130
_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5565"

2: size: 4 stock: 10
_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5564"

3: {_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5563",  size: 4.5,  stock: 30}

4: size: 5 stock: 53
_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5562" ]
```

4) These are the functions that I am running:

> onClick={() => this.alertBox(prod, arr, item)}

```
alertBox = (product, products, count) => {
        console.log(count)
        let newStock;
        let clickedSize;
        let selectedProduct;

        if (product.stock === 0) { 
            alert('The item is currently out of stock')
        } else {
            newStock = product.stock -= 1;  
            clickedSize = product.size;
            selectedProduct = product._id;
            let newProducts;
            let quantity = 0;

            products.map((item) => {
                return item._id === product._id ? 
                    newProducts = [...this.state.chosenSize , {...item, ...newStock }]
                    : product
            });
            const tester = [];
            const result = [];
            const newSize = [];
            let quantities = [];
            let items;
            let newIt;

            newProducts.forEach(function(el) {
                if (tester.indexOf(el._id) === -1) {
                    tester.push(el._id)
                    result.push(el)
                    items = {...el}
                }
            });

            let newArray = result.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, item.stock -= 1));

            this.setState(prevState => ({
                chosenSize: newArray
            }))

        }
    }
```

and

> onClick={() => this.onUpdateItem(idx, arr, prod)}

```
onUpdateItem = (i, product, prod) => { 
       let newProd = product.stock;
           this.setState({
            chosenSize: product.map(el => (el._id === prod._id ? Object.assign({}, el, el.stock -= 1) : el))
     }); 

    };
```

7) I want the object to update to something like this after each click.

> 3: {_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5563",  size: 4.5,  stock: 30, quantity:
>   1 }
>
> to
>
> 3: {_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5563",  size: 4.5,  stock: 29, quantity:
>   2 }
>
> to
>
> 3: {_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5563",  size: 4.5,  stock: 28, quantity:
>   3 }

This is the code sandbox for this project although for whatever reason it is not rendering my components anymore. The code is in the ProductPage file [codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-roentgen-7mp0t](http://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-roentgen-7mp0t).

### Edit

My apologies, the code sandbox now works, you just have to click on one of the items and it will take you to the product page
http://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-roentgen-7mp0t

Comment: Can you just undo and check what was making your code run and compare with the new version?

Comment: Wait I am sorry, what do you mean by undo?  Do you mean to delete one of the functions?

Comment: "Not rendering my components anymore" - revert to when it was rendering and check what changed. If you can tell us what changes you added, that would be easy for us to debug.

Comment: Oh got it, the sandbox

Comment: It works now boss! you just have to click on one of the items and it will take you to the item with the sizes!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `import { Link } from "react-router-dom";` to make the `Link` work in `Product.js`. I just made the changes to the code sandbox

Comment: Thanks boss, it seems to now work, I did it a few minutes ago but perhaps it didn't work before. Do you have any idea how to make the code work? I haven't been able to solve this and it has been a week :(

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Basically I want to create an array of objects with only the selected sizes for example:                                                                                   3: {_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5563", size: 4.5, stock: 30, quantity: 1 }

to

3: {_id: "5d903adb01cdab06932b5563", size: 4.5, stock: 29, quantity: 2 }                                                                                                                         So on the first click, I want for the object to be added to the array and on the second click, I want to stock to decrease by one so from 30 to 29.

Comment: I am not understanding which part of the code do you want to make changes to and which part of the code do you want to manipulate.

Comment: Basically I want to do two things:  1) I want to create an array of unique objects based on the size that the client clicks 2) The object in the array will only object the stock once it is added to the new object array. 3) The stock should basically decrease by one every time the user clicks on the size. 4) If the user clicks on a size, it will decrease its stock by one and add the object to the array.

Comment: Hey man I updated the code now the only function that matters is "updateArray", the only problem that I am having now is that it won't decrease the "stock" by one when I click on the size and it won't increase the "product" by one either. It is probably super easy for you but for some reason both quantities are not updating on click.